# keyboard shortcut to open a minimised window?

Tags: keyboard, email, shortcut

If I use Mail and double click a message to open that message in a new window, then minimise the main mail window, then switch to a different app, what keyboard shortcut(s) can I use to bring back to main mail window, leaving the message window open?

Answer (score 2):

1. <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> until you find the Mail application
2. Before releasing <kbd>⌘</kbd>, hold down the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> button

Comment: This does not completely answer what was asked in the OP. I'd suggest you reread the OP and amend your answer. Additionally, while `⌘Tab` will enable you to go back to Mail, `⌘\`` will not restore the minimized main window as asked in the OP.

Comment: My bad @user3439894, let me re-update answer to work accordingly.

Comment: I don't see how holding option changes anything. The main Mail window remains minimised. Yes, I see the message window, but ⌘-tab already does that. I want to use a keyboard shortcut to switch to the main window, which is minimsed; ⌘tab doesn't; ⌘` doesn't; ⌘⌥ tab or ` doesn't.

Comment: @frumbert Please read my solution. You don't hold that key. While ⌘tab, release Tab and hold ⌥ Option

Comment: yes, this is precicely what i did and it does NOT bring the minimised mail window back up, sorry.

Comment: Not sure why this isn't working for you, however I tested on a friend's computer as well and this does work @frumbert

Comment: This worked for me after it was updated. +1